# Is there an equivalent function for fill_n in C?

Tags: c++, c

If I wanted to translate `fill_n` function from CPP to C what would that look like?

If I have two `fill_n` function below and I wanted to populate it `0` in C how would I do that?

```
fill_n(vaToPa, number_of_virtual_memory, 0);
fill_n(paToVa, number_of_physical_memory, 0);
```

Comment: There's no such standard C function. It is however easy to implement using a plain `for` loop. Or in the case of setting all the bytes to zero, use `memset`.

Answer (score 2):

For bytes, you can use `memset`. For `wchar_t` you can use `wmemset`. Apart from that, the standard library doesn't have a generic function for filling. You can make one, but it won't look as clean as templates, so you might want to use a plain for loop in most cases. It would maybe look something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_fill_n(void *base, const void *fill, size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    for (char *i = base; i < (char *)base + nmemb * size; i += size)
        memcpy(i, fill, size);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];
    my_fill_n(a, &(int){42}, sizeof a / sizeof *a, sizeof *a);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
```

Note that `my_fill_n` is also limited compared to `std::fill_n` in that it will only work with arrays, not any other data structures.

Comment: It might be good to mention that unlike `std::fill_n`, this function works only with arrays and not other data structures.

Comment: @eerorika you're right, edited to add, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent function for fill_n in C?

No, there is no equivalent function template in C. There are no function templates at all in C.

It is quite simple however and such function can be implemented using a loop.

> If I have two fill_n function below and I wanted to populate it 0 in C how would I do that?
>
> ```
> fill_n(vaToPa, number_of_virtual_memory, 0);
> fill_n(paToVa, number_of_physical_memory, 0);
> ```

That depends on the types of vaToPa and paToVa. If they're arrays or pointers, then in case of 0, you can use memset:

```
memset(vaToPa, 0, number_of_virtual_memory * sizeof(*vaToPa));
```

Comment: in the case of vaToPa and paToVa they are pointer, so would this work?
 memset(vaToPa,0,sizeof(number_of_virtual_memory));
   memset(paToVa,0,sizeof(number_of_physical_memory));

Comment: @anthony no, that wouldn't work. See my example. Also see the documentation of memset and the documentation of what sizeof does.

Comment: @anthony Probably not, since e.g. `sizeof(number_of_virtual_memory)` is the size of the `number_of_virtual_memory` variable itself. The size should be the size (in bytes) of the memory that `vaToPa` is pointing to. Which I assume is the *value* of `number_of_virtual_memory`.